# Is there a "missing" function in Python?

Tags: python, parameters

In R, there is a `missing()` function to test, quote : "whether a value was specified as an argument to a function" :

```
my_function <- function(argn1){
  if(missing(argn1)){
    print("argn1 has not been supplied")
  } else {
    print("argn1 has been supplied")  
  }
}
```

Then when calling :

```
my_function("hello")
```

> [1] "argn1 has been supplied"

```
my_function()
```

> [1] "argn1 has not been supplied"

Is there such a thing in Python ?

Comment: You could just have a signature like `def foo(arg=None): if arg is None: print('missing arg')...`, although semantically this is not the same

Comment: Actually, it's a good thing there isn't a missing function, because Python has something called the TypeError it throws at you if you do things you're not supposed to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well usually arguments **without a default value** are **mandatory**. So you can **provide a default object** `missing` for instance to check whether the attribute was given explicitly. Like:

```
missing = object()

def foo(arg1 = missing):
    if arg1 is missing:
        print('Arg1 is missing')
    else:
        print('Arg1 is not missing')
```

Using the `is` over `==` can be of *vital* importance, since `is` checks reference equality.

Sometimes one uses `None`, like:

```
def foo(arg1 = None):
    if arg1 is None:
        # ...
```

But note that here Python cannot make a difference between an implicit argument, like `foo()` or an explicit call with `None`, like `foo(None)`.

Furthermore there is also the option to use `*args`:

```
def foo(*args):
    # ...
```

If you call `foo(None,1)` then all the arguments will be put into a tuple an that tuple is named `args` (here `args` will be `args = (None,1)`). So then we can check if the tuple contains at least one element:

```
def foo(*args):
    if args:
        print('At least one element provided')
    else:
        print('No element provided')
```

Comment: Thanks for that complete answer. Which option would you consider a best practice ?

Comment: @fmalaussena: if the arguments have a semantical meaning, the former. Only if the number of arguments is variable because you want for instance calculate say the maximum of the parameters, the second is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

No, because Python does not support calling a function with the wrong number of arguments. If you define a function to take one argument (without a default):

```
def my_func(arg1):
    pass
```

and then call it just via `my_func()`, Python will raise a TypeError.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no `missing` function.

However, you can do the same thing by using function arguments with default values:

```
def foo(arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        print('arg is missing.')
    else:
        print('arg is present.')
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, you will often find this kind of function declaration:

```
def my_function(arg1=None):
    if arg1:
        # Do something

    else:
        # Do something else
```

to achieve what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

There is no obvious equivalent. But you can use **default parameters**.

```
def my_function(str=None):
    if str is None:
        print("argn1 has not been supplied")
    else:
        print("argn1 has been supplied")
```